# How can I straighten my character's legs?

Tags: modeling

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sAEc0K6DQc&list=PLn3ukorJv4vtf9E9IQk7Acbe7cKkEnuyk&index=4) by Grant Abbitt on the deadpool Funko Pop. When I came to the legs part, I extruded / grabbed it the same way he did, followed his same steps and even redid it a few times. But my legs are slanted, whereas his isn't.

In the pictures below, the reason my front view has the feet but his doesn't is because I couldn't fine a scene where he turned to the front view.

My front view:

[image: Front View (Mine)]

His front view:

[image: Front View (His)]

My side view:

[image: Side View (Mine)]

His side view:

[image: Side View (His)]

So my question is, how can I straighten my character's legs? I have tried rotating, grabbing, etc. but it still doesn't help.

Thank you!

[image]

EDIT: Umm also, I can't undo the legs and feet...unless I make another torso.

Comment: Difficult to tell without seeing your model in edit mode showing the edges, but it may be because you didn't rotate the legs at knee level in front view before extruding on downwards towards the feet. Can you upload the blend file please?

Comment: @JohnEason thanks for the suggestion, how do I share my blend file? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry. Please upload it to [blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: @JohnEason got it, thanks!

Comment: Ok. I've compared your file to mine at the same stage (end of video 3 in my case) and it looks as if your body is too wide which has made the top of the legs too far apart. In addition you should have rotated the leg at the ankle before extruding down to create the foot. If you're a relative beginner following a series of videos, I'd always advise 'saving as' (SHIFT-CTRL-S) at the end of each video and increasing the number in the filename each time. That way you can easily go back to the previous stage and try again.

Comment: @JohnEason thank you for your advise, does that mean I have to redo my body again to make the fix the legs? Thank you again!

Comment: No. You can remodel it easily by box or circle selecting the vertices you want to move in wireframe mode (Z-key) and then using the G-key  to grab the selected vertices and move them around. This isn't really the place for detailed instructions though so I'd suggest reading up on the subject and having a play. You can always undo actions you've just made with CTRL-Z.